# Not able to Post facebook Checkin status Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

Error:

> Response={   "error": {      "message": "(#100) Requires extended permission: publish_checkins or publish_actions",      "type": "OAuthException",      "code": 100   }}

Source Code:

```
Bundle params1 = new Bundle();
    params1.putString("access_token",token);
    params1.putString("place", "566414493392930");  // YOUR PLACE ID
    params1.putString("message","I m here in this place");
    JSONObject coordinates = new JSONObject();
    try {
        coordinates.put("latitude", "30.902823300000000000");
        coordinates.put("longitude", "75.830516900000020000");
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    params1.putString("coordinates",coordinates.toString());
    params1.putString("tags",params[0]);//where xx indicates the User Id
    String response="";
    try {

    response =faceBook.request("me/checkins", params1, "POST");
        Log.v("Response","Response="+response);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error says that the permissions: `publish_checkins` or `publish_actions` is required. To remove this error, simply add these permissions while authenticating the user. See how it is done: [Android login- permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook#permissions)

But, the thing is- the API **checkins have been deprecated**. [Check here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/checkins/) it says-

> Checkins have been deprecated in favor of attaching place information to posts, or tagging places in Open Graph stories. Please check the related guides for information.

So your code shall not work anyway. You'll now have to use [Open Graph Actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions#places) for the same. There's step wise tutorial for the same in the documentation, just go through it and implement. Good luck.

Comment: I tried to implement the way you suggested but the problem is that i m getting response Code: 200 but I am not able to see Check-in Status on my Facebook

Comment: yes done it. I was using the wrong Http Method.Now I made it correct and it stared working. Thank u @Sahil Mittal